# Copying and renaming sheets

Tags: vba, excel

Could someone please help me work out how to copy and rename sheets based on values on another sheet,
currently the sheet is being called "CLO (2)" not "CLO 1.2". I want the code to copy the sheet named "CLO" and rename it based on values found on the sheet called "TMP Data", using the cell values from B7 and C7 and below (B and C values create the sheet name).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Target.Address = "$B$6" Then

        Application.EnableEvents = False

        With Target.Offset(1, 0)

            Range(.Cells(1), .Cells(1).End(xlDown)).ClearContents

            .Value = 1

            .Resize(Target.Value, 1).DataSeries _

              Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlLinear, Step:=1

        End With

        Target.Offset(0, 1).Activate

    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Columns("C")) Is Nothing Then

        If Target.Row > 6 And Application.Count(Target.Offset(0, -1).Resize(1, 2)) = 2 Then

            On Error GoTo Fìn

            Application.EnableEvents = False

            Dim w As Long

            For w = 1 To Target.Value

                Sheets("CLO").Copy(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = _

                  Target.Offset(0, -1) & Chr(46) & w

            Next w

            Me.Activate

        End If

    End If
Fìn:

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

[Here is the Excel file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2mcZKXhV5wob2oxTlNRQ0tPOUpOajRjT2Y4ZjNNby1CUU1Z/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: So what's going wrong? Are you getting an error? Wrong results? There's a lot of code here to be renaming some sheets...

Comment: The user puts in some numbers on the TMP Data sheet, this is then supposed to copy a sheet called CLO x amount of times and give each sheet a unique number from the information on the TMP data sheet.

Comment: Okay. *and what actually happens?*

Comment: It just creates one copy of the sheet and calls it "CLO (2)"

Comment: The code below works, but instead of just adding blank sheets I need it to copy the Sheet called CLO and use the naming convention.   `            For w = 1 To Target.Value
                Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = _
                  Target.Offset(0, -1) & Chr(46) & w`

Comment: Should `Target.Offset(0, -1) & Chr(46) & w` be `Target.Offset(0, -1).Value & Chr(46) & w`? It looks like you're not using the value of the range to name the sheet...

Comment: Calling `Copy()` on a worksheet doesn't return a reference to the resulting copy.  You have to rename it in a separate operation.  If you comment out the error handler you will see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

By default the sheet will be copied as CLO (2),  rename it after it has been copied:

```
Sheets("CLO").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = Target.Offset(0, -1).Value & Chr(46) & w
```